# "undefined identifier" despite defining it in the class.

Tags: c++

im a beginner in c++ and i am so confused why i am getting an error in my code, could you guys please tell me whats going wrong? im using visual studios 2017.

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 


class Cat {
private:
bool happy;
public:
void speak() {
    cout << "meow" << endl;
}
Cat() { 
    bool newHappy = happy;
    happy = true;
}
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Starting program..." << endl;

    Cat bob;
    bob.speak();

    if (happy) {
        cout << "cat is happy" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "unhappy cat" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Ending program..." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is `happy` in `if (happy) {`?

Comment: Post your error

Comment: "An error" isn't helpful. The question title is a bit better but still not enough information. Which line is this about? Which identifier?

Comment: I would *guess* that it's about the `happy` in the line `if (happy)`. Just like you need to call `bob.speak()` to clarify that `bob` is speaking, you need to check if *`bob`* is happy, as opposed to any other potential `Cat`, with `bob.happy` (although as alter igel points out in the answers, that won't work because happiness is private).

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to reference a variable called `happy` inside your main function, which doesn't exist in that scope. If you want to see if `bob` is happy, you could simply write `if (bob.happy){ ...` and change `Cat::happy` from `private` to `public`, or you could create a getter function like:

```
class Cat {
    private:
    bool happy;
    public:
    bool isHappy() const {
        return happy;
    }
    ...
};
```

and call the function as follows: `if (bob.isHappy()){ ...`

Comment: Thanks so much dude. (sorry for the vagueness in my question im not really used to this) your explanation was really helpful, thanks!!!